# clang++ error: () from module () is not present in definition of () in module ()

Tags: c++, boost, clang, c++20, c++-modules

Clang and libc++ version: 15.0.7

#### Source

as.cppm:

```cpp
export module as;
import <boost/asio.hpp>;
// import <iostream>;
export int main() {
}
```

#### Compile

(needs boost library)

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ --precompile -xc++-system-header boost/asio.hpp
#Produces `asio.pcm`
clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ --precompile as.cppm -fmodule-file=asio.pcm
#Produces `as.pcm`
```

Everything works well

But if I uncomment line 3

#### Source:

as.cppm:

```cpp
export module as;
import <boost/asio.hpp>;
import <iostream>;
export int main() {
}
```

#### Compile

(needs boost library)

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ --precompile -xc++-system-header boost/asio.hpp
#Produces `asio.pcm`
clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ --precompile -xc++-system-header iostream
#Produces `iostream.pcm`
clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ --precompile as.cppm -fmodule-file=asio.pcm -fmodule-file=iostream.pcm
#Error
```

#### Error

[pastebin](https://controlc.com/4141f135)

Why is it producing such error messages? I cannot find similar ones across google.

g++ 12.2 produces *internal compiler error* on the same code

Comment: `(stackoverflow says this is code` if you use code formatting then it is considered as code, if you dont want it to appear as code, dont use code formatting

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number If I remove the code formatting then it won't let me post

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thank you for your editing, but Idk what you mean from your link. This is just my original version of question but denied by stackoverflow for ridiculous reasons

Comment: the links was the wrong one. I though the external link is to an image. Anyhow, you should include the error in the quesiton, not only a link to an external site

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number including the error messes up the entire question. There is no <details> in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered a similar problem to yours.

In my case, I imported `<format>` and `<iostream>` together.

```
$ clang++-18 -std=c++26 -x c++-system-header format iostream -stdlib=libc++
# Produces `format.pcm` and `iostream.pcm`

$ clang++-18 -std=c++26 -fmodule-file=format.pcm -fmodule-file=iostream.pcm -x c++ - -stdlib=libc++
import <format>;
import <iostream>;
int main() { std::cout << std::format("clang {}\n", __clang_major__); }
# Many errors like this:
/usr/lib/llvm-18/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:344:5: error: 'std::basic_string_view<char>::basic_string_view' from module '/usr/lib/llvm-18/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream' is not present in definition of 'std::string_view' in module '/usr/lib/llvm-18/bin/../include/c++/v1/format'
```

The culprit is `<string_view>` in this case. Since both `<format>` and `<iostream>` include `<string_view>` directly or indirectly, generating `format.pcm` and `iostream.pcm` separately might mess up dependencies, leading to problems in the ODR Checking and declarations merging when parsing `import <format>;` and `import <iostream>;`. (See [the official document](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/StandardCPlusPlusModules.html#known-problems))

A temporary workaround might be generating `string_view.pcm` first and then generating `format.pcm` and `iostream.pcm` based on `string_view.pcm`.

```
$ clang++-18 -std=c++26 -x c++-system-header string_view -stdlib=libc++
# Produces `string_view.pcm`

$ clang++-18 -std=c++26 -fmodule-file=string_view.pcm -x c++-system-header format iostream -stdlib=libc++
# Produces `format.pcm` and `iostream.pcm` (with the same `string_view.pcm` dependency)

$ clang++-18 -std=c++26 -fmodule-file=format.pcm -fmodule-file=iostream.pcm -x c++ - -stdlib=libc++
import <format>;
import <iostream>;
int main() { std::cout << std::format("clang {}\n", __clang_major__); }
# Produces `a.out`

$ ./a.out
clang 18
```

In your case, you might generate `stdexcept.pcm` first and then generate `asio.pcm` and `iostream.pcm` based on `stdexcept.pcm`.

Remember not to use this feature in a production environment until the compiler has stable support for it. You might also try the [`Standard Library Modules`](https://libcxx.llvm.org/Modules.html) feature, which is much more convenient - only an `import std;` statement is needed.

Comment: Thanks for help! I will never use those unstable features anymore